# Unable to get only first occurrence of each job

Tags: oracle, top-n

I am trying to query some jobs from a repo, however I only need the job with the latest start time. I have tried using ROW_NUMBER for this and select only row number 1 for each job, however it doesn't seem to fall through:

```
SELECT a.jobname||','||a.projectname||','||a.startdate||','||a.enddate||','||
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY a.jobname ORDER BY a.startdate DESC ) AS "rowID"
FROM taskhistory a
WHERE a.jobname IS NOT NULL AND a.startdate >= (SYSDATE-1))LIMIT 1 AND rowID = 1;


ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected ROWID got NUMBER
```

Can I please ask for some assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have aliased your concatenated string `"rowID"` which is a mistake because it clashes with the Oracle keyword `rowid`.  This is a special datatype, which allows us to identify table rows by their physical location.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns008.htm#SQLRF00254).

When you reference the column alias you omitted the fouble quotes.  Oracle therefore interprets it as the keyword, `rowid`, and expects an expression which can be converted to the ROWID datatype.

Double-quoted identifiers are always a bad idea.  Avoid them unless truly necessary.

Fixing the column alias will reveal the logic bug in your code.  You are concatenating a whole slew of columns together, including the ROW_NUMBER() function, and calling that string "rowID".  Clearly that string is never going to equal one, so this will filter out all rows:

```
and "rowID" = 1
```

Also LIMIT is not valid in Oracle.

What you need to do is use a sub-query, like this

```
SELECT a.jobname||','
       ||a.projectname||','
       ||a.startdate||','
       ||a.enddate||','
       ||to_char(a.rn) as "rowID"
FROM (
    SELECT jobname
            , projectname
            , startdatem 
            , enddate, 
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY jobname 
                                  ORDER BY startdate DESC ) AS RN
    FROM taskhistory 
    WHERE jobname IS NOT NULL 
    AND a.startdate >= (SYSDATE-1)
    ) a
where a.RN = 1;
```

Concatenating the projection like that seems an odd thing to do but I don't understand your business requirements.

Comment: Your answer is more than great! I wasn't really aware about 'rowid' being a keyword, however now I know. The concatenation is required because I am running the query hourly via crontab&sqlplus, and require the output to be csv in order to parse it easier. Anyhow, thanks a bunch for your answer!